# WPF DynamicDataDisplay - Putting strings in Y Axis instead of numbers

Tags: c#, wpf, string, dynamic-data-display

Using WPF (not Silverlight) D3, is it possible to put strings on the Y axis?
I am specifically talking about a situation in which I have a graph of a timeline with status values (let's say "High" and "Medium" and "Low" mapped as 1, 0 and -1) and want the status on the y axis ticks instead of the numbers...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a LabelProvider to achieve your desired effect. You will have to make a new LabelProvider class that stems off of either LabelProviderBase, or more specifically in your case, NumericLabelProviderBase. You should be able to take all the ticks you have (1,0-1) and change them into strings using an if or a switch in your new LabelProviderClass. There's tons of examples in the source of label providers you can use as a base.

The method you are looking to override is CreateLabels. Here is a quick method I whipped up that should (hopefully!) get you where you need to be. Implement in the new class you create.

```
public override UIElement[] CreateLabels(ITicksInfo<double> ticksInfo) {            

        var ticks = ticksInfo.Ticks;
        Init(ticks);            

        UIElement[] res = new UIElement[ticks.Length];
        LabelTickInfo<double> tickInfo = new LabelTickInfo<double> { Info = ticksInfo.Info };
        for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++) {
            tickInfo.Tick = ticks[i];
            tickInfo.Index = i;
            string labelText = "";

            if(Convert.ToInt32(tickInfo.Tick) == 1) {
                labelText = "High";
            } else if(Convert.ToInt32(tickInfo.Tick) == 0) {
                labelText = "Medium"
            } else if(Convert.ToInt32(tickInfo.Tick) == -1) {
                labelText = "Low"
            } else {
                labelText = ""
            }

            TextBlock label = (TextBlock)GetResourceFromPool();
            if (label == null) {
                label = new TextBlock();
            }

            label.Text = labelText;
            label.ToolTip = ticks[i].ToString();

            res[i] = label;

            ApplyCustomView(tickInfo, label);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

To assign this new LabelProvider to a ChartPlotter, name the axis that you want to label in XAML or create it as an object in C# :

```
yAxis.LabelProvider = new ZazkapulskLabelProvider();
```

Comment: Jason, I should take you on retainer. Thanks again. Would you show me how to use this method in the definition of a plotter = new ChartPlotter?

Comment: Jason, what's your address? Where to send the flowers to? BTW, have you seen this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378180/wpf-dynamicdatadisplay-slow-plotting-with-markers?

Comment: Haha, no worries! I've been working with this library for a while and was sad to see there was no documentation. I'm glad to help people who had to go through the same struggle I did! As long as you accept the answer and possible throw some upvotes, I'm happy ;)

Answer (score 0):

Dont use upper solution. Make my VS many compiler errors. I'm trying that solution on VS2013 on 3 hours but didnt work. Use that solution wherein function draw graph  :

```
 dimSeviyesiAxis.LabelProvider.CustomFormatter = (tickInfo) =>
        {
            return "%" + tickInfo.Tick.ToString();
        };
```

Which dimSeviyesiAxis is xaml axis name made the axis label starts with "%". Before return you can code any conditional statements. Here is the source link :

http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/discussions/462842