# WPF DynamicDataDisplay - Slow plotting with Markers

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, marker, dynamic-data-display

I am having a really hard time waiting for the ChartPlotter in D3 to show itself, when using markers. Of course I am trying to plot a Gazillion records (well, 700,000 records). When using just a line, all is well (20 seconds or so). When using markers, we're talking 5 minutes. That's not acceptable.

Any ideas?

Here's what I have done, with explanations under it.

```
public static string MakeSimplePlot(double[][] xData, double[][] yData, string[] legend, string xAxisTitle, string yAxisTitle, bool[] showLines, bool[] showMarkers)
    {
        ChartPlotter plotter = new ChartPlotter();

        plotter.MainHorizontalAxis = new HorizontalAxis();
        plotter.MainVerticalAxis = new VerticalAxis();

        HorizontalAxisTitle horizontalAxisTitle = new HorizontalAxisTitle();
        horizontalAxisTitle.Content = xAxisTitle;
        plotter.AddChild(horizontalAxisTitle);

        VerticalAxisTitle verticalAxisTitle = new VerticalAxisTitle();
        verticalAxisTitle.Content = yAxisTitle;
        plotter.AddChild(verticalAxisTitle);

        Color[] plotColors = new Color[13] { Colors.Blue, Colors.Red, Colors.Green, Colors.Chartreuse, Colors.Yellow, Colors.Violet, Colors.Tan, Colors.Silver, Colors.Salmon, Colors.Lime, Colors.Brown, Colors.Chartreuse, Colors.DarkGray };

        for (int seriesCounter = 0; seriesCounter < legend.Count(); seriesCounter++)
        {
            DataFile clearedInputs = ClearExcess(new DataFile(xData[seriesCounter], yData[seriesCounter]));
            xData[seriesCounter] = clearedInputs.time;
            yData[seriesCounter] = clearedInputs.data;

            var xDataSource = new EnumerableDataSource<double>(xData[seriesCounter]);
            xDataSource.SetXMapping(x => x);

            var yDataSource = new EnumerableDataSource<double>(yData[seriesCounter]);
            yDataSource.SetYMapping(x => x);

            CompositeDataSource plotSeries = new CompositeDataSource(xDataSource, yDataSource);

            CirclePointMarker circlePointMarker = new CirclePointMarker();
            circlePointMarker.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(plotColors[seriesCounter]);
            circlePointMarker.Pen = new Pen(circlePointMarker.Fill, 0);

            circlePointMarker.Size = (showMarkers[seriesCounter] == false) ? 0 : 8;
            int lineWidth = (showLines[seriesCounter] == false) ? 0 : 2;

            if (showMarkers[seriesCounter] == false)
            {
                plotter.AddLineGraph(plotSeries, new Pen(circlePointMarker.Fill, lineWidth), new PenDescription("Dummy"));
            }
            else
            {
                plotter.AddLineGraph(plotSeries, new Pen(circlePointMarker.Fill, lineWidth), circlePointMarker, new PenDescription("Dummy"));
            }
        }

        UIParameters.plotWindow.mainGrid.Children.Clear();
        UIParameters.plotWindow.mainGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();
        UIParameters.plotWindow.mainGrid.Children.Add(plotter);
        plotter.Viewport.FitToView();

        plotter.LegendVisible = false;
        plotter.NewLegendVisible = false;            

        if (legend.Count() > 1)
        {
            ShowLegend(legend, plotColors);
        }

        UIParameters.plotWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        UIParameters.plotWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

        string filename = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), "png");

        RenderTargetBitmap targetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)UIParameters.plotWindow.mainGrid.ActualWidth, (int)UIParameters.plotWindow.mainGrid.ActualHeight, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);
        targetBitmap.Render(UIParameters.plotWindow.mainGrid);
        PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(targetBitmap));
        using (var fileStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            encoder.Save(fileStream);
            UIParameters.plotWindow.mainGrid.Clip = null;

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();

            targetBitmap.Freeze();

            if (targetBitmap != null) targetBitmap.Clear();
            targetBitmap = null;
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }

        return filename;
    }
```

Explanations:

1. I hide the plotter legend and make my own using ShowLegend, since the legend does not show if it has only markers (am I wrong?)
2. I minimize and maximize the plot window, since otherwise the plot does not update, or it updates but does not get saved to a file. This also works if I move the window (I guess some kind of redraw event), but since the process is autoamatic, the user does not have any interaction. I tries Invalidate, to no avail. Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, I just noticed.. you have Chartreuse in your colour list twice!

Comment: unrelated to your question, my version of D3 library has no ChartPlotter.MainHorizontalAxis property (nor AddChild). I downloaded the library from codeplex, and I have version 0.3. Is there a more recent version? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote my own class to hide markers when they are off screen. It's a virtualization technique that speeds up performance tenfold when you don't have tons of markers on screen. It looks like this :

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.DataSources;
using Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.PointMarkers;
using Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.Common;

namespace Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.Charts {
public class FilteredMarkerPointsGraph : MarkerPointsGraph {
    public FilteredMarkerPointsGraph()
        : base() {
        ;
    }

    public FilteredMarkerPointsGraph(IPointDataSource dataSource)
        : base(dataSource) {
        ;
    }

    protected override void OnRenderCore(DrawingContext dc, RenderState state) {
        // base.OnRenderCore
        if (DataSource == null) return;
        if (Marker == null) return;

        var left = Viewport.Visible.Location.X;
        var right = Viewport.Visible.Location.X + Viewport.Visible.Size.Width;
        var top = Viewport.Visible.Location.Y;
        var bottom = Viewport.Visible.Location.Y + Viewport.Visible.Size.Height;

        var transform = Plotter2D.Viewport.Transform;

        DataRect bounds = DataRect.Empty;
        using (IPointEnumerator enumerator = DataSource.GetEnumerator(GetContext())) {
            Point point = new Point();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
                enumerator.GetCurrent(ref point);                                       

                if (point.X >= left && point.X <= right && point.Y >= top && point.Y <= bottom)
                {
                    enumerator.ApplyMappings(Marker);

                    Point screenPoint = point.DataToScreen(transform);

                    bounds = DataRect.Union(bounds, point);
                    Marker.Render(dc, screenPoint);
                }
            }
        }

        Viewport2D.SetContentBounds(this, bounds);
    }
}
```

Make sure you call FilteredMarkerPointsGraph in the XAML instead of MarkerPointsGraph!

**EDIT**

1. I'm not sure what you need with the legend with markers, I've not actually used a legend in any of my graphs, but your solution seems to be fine.
2. Redrawing the plot is quite easy actually.

The best way that I have found to do this, is to have a Property in your code behind that represents the DataSource and bind the chart's DataSource to that property. Have your code behind implement INotifyPropertyChanged and call OnPropertyChanged every time you update or re-assign your data source. This will force the plotter to observe the binding and redraw your graph.

Example:

```
EnumerableDataSource<Point> m_d3DataSource;
public EnumerableDataSource<Point> D3DataSource {
get {
    return m_d3DataSource;
}
set {                
    //you can set your mapping inside the set block as well             
    m_d3DataSource = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("D3DataSource");
}
}     

protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) {
        handler(this, e);
    }
} 

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
    OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

And about your performance with your markers.. It's hard to pinpoint exactly what would be causing your performance issue, but my recommendation is to try using a different data source. I've been using EnumerableDataSource and it's always worked like a charm. Try bringing in your data in a singular object and setting the mapping in your set block like as shown above using:

```
value.SetYMapping(k => Convert.ToDouble(k.yData));
value.SetXMapping(k => Convert.ToDouble(k.xData));
```

The only thing you have to worry about is the mapping in Enumerable data source and D3 should handle the rest for you.

Comment: I just saw your comment on Felice's post.. not so sure this is the answer you are looking for if you can't manipulate the graph. This only virtualizes points off screen. Maybe you could explain your project a little more and a better solution might be at hand?

Comment: Jason: Thanks (again...). I am writing an automatic report generator for an electronic process. Instead of the user opening a new word document, writing it from scratch, making his own graphs in matlab and THEN analyzing the results, I want to provide the user with a form with all the graphs done - just add explanations. Most of the data are electronic status files and are of hundreds of thousands records. Hope this explains it. Thanks, again.

Comment: Are you making multiple chart plotters at once? I've found that plotting markers is quite quick, only manipulating them is what causes my slow down. How do you have your source applied to the graph? I have mine done through XAML binding on an EnumerableDataSource, and mapping works like a charm. Maybe you could play around with the different Data Sources (For instance, I know EnumerableDataSource is alot quicker than ObservableDataSource!), or the problem might be with how you actually parse the data before you plot it! Maybe you could pinpoint  exactly where you get your slowdown.

Comment: Jason, I edited my question, hopefully it answers your questions. Any advice would help. Thanks

Comment: Jason - I've read everything you wrote, and it's quite helpful, again. What do you mean by "singular object"? and how do I "use a different data source"? Thanks a million.

Comment: I just mean package your xData and yData into an object and pass it into your graph that way, and use that object to map your data. When I say use a different data source, I mean, try an EnumerableDataSource or ObservableDataSource instead of CompositeDataSource. All my code examples above use EnumerableDataSource, and I would recommend trying to use it. Might speed up your performance.

Comment: Jason, why packaging the data would accelerate the function? And would you please explain how to exactly change the usage from CompositeDataSource to EnumerableDataSource in my question (CompositeDataSource plotSeries = new CompositeDataSource(xDataSource, yDataSource))?

Comment: Well, it all has to do with the mapping, if you have both pieces of data in the same object, you can pass that object to the mapping. I will update my answer with an example of mapping the EnumerableDataSource.

Comment: Well, if you insist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437250/manipulating-simple-bookmarks-in-word

Comment: Actually, Jason, I used your idea and switched to EnumerableDataSource. The plots run faster, but when I use markers as in the code above, it still takes minutes... I think I'm going to give up on markers.

Comment: Hmm, well I'm slowly running out of ideas. Haha. Are you absolutely sure that it's plotting the markers that slows you down as opposed to actually handling the data that your markers represent? If you are, it seems that your options are narrowed down to starting the graph at a more zoomed in level, and virtualizing the markers draw to only drawing what's on screen as per my answer above.

Comment: I see. thanks. While I am paying you (hehehe), can you enlighten me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437250/manipulating-simple-bookmarks-in-word?

Comment: I'm afraid you would know much more than me on that subject, I've only briefly used OpenXML! But if I come across anything in my travels, I'll let you know!

Answer (score 1):

Well user can't probably see markers anyway when you are displaying the "Gazillion" of points: can't you switch the mode from line to markers when the zoom level is more reasonable ?

Comment: Hi Felice. The user doesn't manipulate the UI. I just make the plot and paste it into word. I can see quite well the markers, and it serves me well.